# Building the second version of my IoT vehicle control unit (VCU) and want to turn on the ignition using FETS instead of relays

Tags: mosfet, relay, bjt, switching

[image]

I need to build the "Circuit" block of this schematic.

The ignition works when the 48V voltage supply is shorted with the ignition cable. Relays worked fine, but I want to remove all moving parts in my VCU, hence looking for FETS or BJTs.

My incomplete knowledge of high side and low side switching has brought me here.

The motor controller is a general BLDC 350W controller.

The ignition wire, when shorted with the 48V supply, draws 60-70mA of current.

Comment: So what's you're question?

Comment: Choose a half bridge rated for 10x motor current for high efficiency.

Comment: Planning to solve it with this https://tinyurl.com/2gc2eukw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A switch closure to a motor controller or ESC (electronic switching controller) usually only needs a low current, so the typical solution would be specified in the ESC (unknown) manual is just an NPN with a 330 ohm base resistor, emitter to ground and collector saturated to enable the ESC.

Any  NPN transistor can switch more than 70 mA to ground easily.

If there is variable remote control involved, this was not asked. Your datasheet is necessary . Most common part chosen for less than 60V is the most common PN2222A transistor.